# Can I say "peerless mission?"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

My friends are telling me that calling a mission *peerless* - a unique mission - is not correct. Is that true? I thought that *unique* is very much equivalent to *peerless*.

Comment: *Peerless* does not mean *unique* - it means *without peer*, without an equal, superior in kind not merely degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can. An article in *The Washington Post* titled "[For Searchers in Iraq, a Peerless Mission](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2007/05/17/AR2007051702377.html)" did just that. It may not be the most common phrasing, but it is valid.

As per the comments, *unique* shouldn't be equated with *peerless*. Someone may have a *unique* hairstyle, but that does not make it *peerless* (the best you've ever seen, surpassed by none). Likewise, an actor may give a *peerless* performance (an unmatched rendition of Hamlet), but it may not be *unique* (others have done it, just not as well).

I agree with FumbleFingers that the construction sounds awkward and isn't one you'd find on a typical basis.

Comment: I guess it's "valid", but it doesn't sound good to me. Nor, to be honest, does [matchless mission](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22matchless+mission%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which actually occurs more than twice as often in Google Books there, with 63 written instances.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a peerless mission ... near Santa Barbara, California...

[image]

Comment: I certainly hope it's peerless. Post-modernism on acid.

Comment: Would [Rambo II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rambo:_First_Blood_Part_II) qualify, too (literal interpretation - without a peer, i.e. solo)?